# How To generate json format from model in codeigniter to Highchart

Tags: mysql, json, codeigniter, highcharts

I Have database

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAteS.jpg ;

how can I display the json data format such as the highcharts drilldown example like this

```
 {
                    name: '2010',
                    data: [{
                        name: 'Republican',
                        y: 5,
                        drilldown: 'republican-2010'
                    }, {
                        name: 'Democrats',
                        y: 2,
                        drilldown: 'democrats-2010'
                    }, {
                        name: 'Other',
                        y: 4,
                        drilldown: 'other-2010'
                    }]
                }, {
                    name: '2014',
                    data: [{
                        name: 'Republican',
                        y: 4,
                        drilldown: 'republican-2014'
                    }, {
                        name: 'Democrats',
                        y: 4,
                        drilldown: 'democrats-2014'
                    }, {
                        name: 'Other',
                        y: 4,
                        drilldown: 'other-2014'
                    }]
                }
```

Comment: Hi @Feri , You can also convert your JSON later, on frontend by JS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', id, 'nama', nama, 'tahun', tahun, 'zone', zone, 'nilai', nilai)) from TableA;`

Answer (score 0):

you need to [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

from the model result, by looping through each record you need to create a structured data like the one shown.

```php
# create an array structure like the one below
$chart_data = array(
    array(
        'name'=> '2010',
        'data'=> array(
            array(
                'name'=> 'Republican',
                'y'=> 5,
                'drilldown'=> 'republican-2010'
            ), 
            array(
                'name'=> 'Democrats',
                'y'=> 2,
                'drilldown'=> 'democrats-2010'
            ), 
            array(
                'name'=> 'Other',
                'y'=> 4,
                'drilldown'=> 'other-2010'
            ),
            ...
        )
    ),
    ...
)
;

$chart_data_json_string = json_encode($chart_data);
// $chart_data_json_string would contain a string that can be parsed into JSON from the front end
// $chart_data_json_string = [{"name":"2010","data":[{"name":"Republican","y":5,"drilldown":"republican-2010"},{"name":"Democrats","y":2,"drilldown":"democrats-2010"},{"name":"Other","y":4,"drilldown":"other-2010"}]}]
```

Use [JSON.parse(json_string)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse the string to json which then can be used
by Highchart

```js
let high_chart_data_str = '<?php $chart_data_json_string ?>';
let high_chart_data = JSON.parse(high_chart_data_str);
```